# How can I manually send order details email to customer in Ubercart?

Tags: ubercart

I have a cron job to read orders from the Ubercart database table, and manually send the order email to the customer.

Usually, when customers checkout in Ubercart, they will get their order email straight away. But in my situation we don't want to automatically send the order to customer because we have some process that needs to be completed before we programmatically send the order email to customers.

How can I manually send the customer's order email in Ubercart?

Comment: Can you create a "view" of the orders for which you want to send such eMail for a specific day?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) in a custom module and get all orders using [uc_order_status_list](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/uc_order_status_list) the return value may contain the email address of the buyer. If not get the order id, use [uc_order_load](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_order!uc_order.module/function/uc_order_load/7) to load the order. Get the email of buyer.

And you're done.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. In the Ubercart store administration section go to orders and you can see your orders there then select the order you want to email and go to invoice and there is the option to email the order:

[image]

Comment: OP wants to set cron job to send order emails